# how can i get the day of the week for a particular given date in Matlab

Tags: matlab

As today is Wednesday with date June 8, 2016. how can i write a code to get the day of given dates:
like what day is Nov 29
I'm trying to create a struct with 
date
day 
month
with month and date as input

Answer (score 1):

Use the builtin `weekday()` function:

```
>> [num, name] = weekday('08-Jun-2016')
num =
     4
name =
Wed
>> [num, name] = weekday('29-Nov-2016')
num =
     3
name =
Tue
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `weekday` function, you can use the `DDD` or `DDDD` formats in the `datestr` function, like this:

```
datestr('08-Jun-2016','DDD')   %Returns the string 'Wed'
datestr('08-Jun-2016','DDDD')  %Returns the string 'Wednesday'
```

Or, to use a more practical format

```
datestr('08-Jun-2016','DDDD, mmmm DD, yyyy')
%  Returns the string: 'Wednesday, June 08, 2016'
```